# Why is if/else structure not being utilized in this method?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

```
public static String winner(String computer,String user)
{
    String win=" ";
    if (computer=="rock" && user=="scissors")
    {
        win="Computer wins! Rock smashes scissors.";
    }
    else if (computer=="paper" && user=="rock")
    {
        win="Computer wins! Paper wraps rock.";
    }
    else if (computer=="scissors" && user=="paper")
    {
        win="Computer wins! Scissors cuts paper.";
    }
    else if (computer==user)
    {
        win="Tie. No winner";
    }
    else if (user=="rock" && computer=="scissors")
    {
        win="YOU win! Rock smashes scissors.";
    }
    else if (user=="paper" && computer=="rock")
    {
        win="YOU win! Paper wraps rock.";
    }
    else if (user=="scissors" && computer=="paper")
    {
        win="YOU win! Scissors cuts paper.";
    }
    return win;
}
```

The method receives 2 lower case strings as parameters. I have checked by printing the parameters. I do not understand why my if else statements are not working. I am simply trying to do the possibles out comes of a rock paper scissors game. Thanks for all your help guys.

Comment: Use `user.equals("rock")` instead of `user=="rock"`

Comment: This must be the 10,000th time "Use string.equals(string)." is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compare strings with `equals` in Java, not `==`, or you will be comparing references, not value.

[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)